# check LDAPSearchResults (Enumeration) is empty

Tags: java, ldap

I have a code where i m querying LDAP by using netscape.ldap and getting the response using 
LDAPSearchResults API.

The code is as below:-

```
LDAPSearchResults res = ldapConnection.search(entrydn, LDAPConnection.SCOPE_SUB, searchFilter, null, false);
```

Here response returned is of type LDAPSearchResults(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-5618-10/netscape/ldap/LDAPSearchResults.html)

Now if response is empty i need to return Boolean false else true.

I cant find a method like `isEmpty()` etc which can check for  `LDAPSearchResults` whether its empty or not.

Thanks

Comment: The documentation link you provided yourself already has the answer in it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oracle documentation you can use the methods `getCount()` or `hasMoreElement()`.

The full code would look as follows:

```
    [...]

    LDAPSearchResults res = ldapConnection.search(entrydn, LDAPConnection.SCOPE_SUB, searchFilter, null, false);

    return res.hasMoreElements();  // Or: return (res.getCount() != 0); 
}
```